# Where is Firefox pouchdb-inspector

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, pouchdb

This could be the motivation I need to move to Chrome for development. Working on an application with PouchDB (syncing with a CouchDB instance). I see everywhere that there are links to a Firefox add-on called PouchDB-Inspector which is meant to join the developer tools arsenal. True for Chrome - which does install and work. Firefox - the link is dead - Not found.
https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/pouchdb-inspector/

Does anyone know where it is? Is it discontinued? Done with? Never to be found again?

Any help would be great? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

This add-on seems to be currently unavailable from addons.mozilla.org, but you can get it from it's github [project page](https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb-fauxton-firefox-addon). The creator also provides a link to the current [xpi file](http://marten-de-vries.nl/files/pouchdb-fauxton.xpi) that you can install manually.